# Ubuntu 18.04 SERVER -cannot connect USB wifi dongle

Tags: 18.04, server, wireless

I have installed clean Ubuntu 18.04 server (no snaps added). I cannot get USB Wi-Fi to connect. I know the USB dongle works.

I have put the wifi info in `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, and the outut of `netplan try` and `netplan apply` all looks OK.

yaml file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets: 
        eno1: 
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
     wifis:
        wlx801f02c0d25:
            access-points:
               'my wifi name':
                     password: 'my wifipassword'
            dhcp4: true
```

The driver for wifi (RT2800) seems to be present.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 7392:7711 Edimax Technology Co. Ltd nlite Wireless Adapter [Ralink RT2870]
```

```
$ ip a 
wlx801f02c0d25: <NO_CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisk mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

`link/ether`... but no IP address, etc.

Do I need additional software package or something else?

Comment: Why can't you connect it? What is wrong exactly?

Comment: `sudo ifconfig wlx801f02c0d25 up`

Comment: Install wpasupplicant. Report back. Also, your .yaml file should use 2 space indents, and no tabs.

Comment: Thanks to all. Installing wpasupplicant `sudo apt install wpasupplicant`was the right answer. I guess the standard Ubuntu 18.04 server installation does NOT include this package by default as it is unusual to use wifi with a server. (but I have reasons to use wifi whilst building the server apps!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented. 
Installing wpasupplicant `sudo apt install wpasupplicant` was the key thing.

I guess the standard Ubuntu 18.04 server installation does NOT include this package by default as it is unusual to use wifi with a server. (but I have reasons to use wifi whilst building the server apps!)